# Circle button css

Tags: css, button, geometry

I'm a beginner and very confused, as a div tag when I give the same width and height with border-radius: 50% it always becomes circle.
but with the tag a in case I want to make a circle button, It doesnt work that way. This is when I try to make a circle border button clickable.

```css
 
.btn {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it..??

Comment: Read about `inline` and `block` level elements and you will be able to answer your own question)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

For `div` tag there is already default property `display:block` given by browser. For anchor tag there is not display property given by browser. You need to add display property to it. That's why use `display:block` or display:inline-`block`. It will work.

```css
.btn {
  display:block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 21):

```css
.round-button {
  width:25%;
}
.round-button-circle {
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:10px solid #cfdcec;
  overflow:hidden;
        
  background: #4679BD; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
  background:#30588e;
}
.round-button a {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:50%;
  padding-bottom:50%;
  line-height:1em;
  margin-top:-0.5em;
        
  text-align:center;
  color:#e2eaf3;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-button"><div class="round-button-circle"><a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a></div></div>
```

or very simple for `<a/>`

```css
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    line-height:80px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #555777;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.round-button:hover {
    background: #777555;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button</a>
```

for jsfiddle reference [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/ut1z5pmg/2/)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a flat design circle button:

[image]

```css
.btn {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;  
  width: 80px;  
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">+</div>
```

but the problem is that the `+` might not be perfectly centered vertically in all browsers / platforms, because of font differences... see also this question (and its answer): [Vertical alignement of span inside a div when the font-size is big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253431/vertical-alignement-of-span-inside-a-div-when-the-font-size-is-big)

Answer (score 8):

For a modern CSS approach, we now have a few tools like [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) and `grid` to create perfect circle buttons like so:

```
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
```

Setting fixed height and width on an inline element (i.e an `a` tag) has no effect. Like mentioned by the others, we need to set the display property to a block element. Using grid allows easy centering and generally more control of the content inside the button.

All together with some optional padding and centering:

(Leaving the red border because OP had it on there)

```
.btn {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 0 2em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This is now compatible with almost all browsers (now that IE is sunset). Of course your project may not allow such modernity but it is nice to start using this stuff when we can.

Answer (score 3):

Add `display: block;`. That's the difference between a `<div>` tag and an `<a>` tag

```
.btn {
      display: block;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

use this css.

```css
.roundbutton{
          display:block;
          height: 300px;
          width: 300px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          border: 1px solid red;
          
        }
```

```html
<a class="roundbutton" href="#"><i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Though I can see an accepted answer and other great answers too but thought of sharing what I did to solve this issue (in just one line).

**CSS ( Created a Class ) :**

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**HTML (Added that css class to my button) :**

```
<a class="button circle button-energized ion-paper-airplane"></a>
```

So Easy Right ?

**Note :** What I actually did was proper use of ionic classes with just one line of css.

**See Result your self on this JSFiddle :**

https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/cnx48u43/

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="bool-answer">
  <div class="answer">Nej</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bool-answer {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For create circle button you are this codes:

```css
.circle-right-btn {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fefefe;
    margin-top: 24px;
    font-size:22px;
}
```

```html
<input  class="circle-right-btn" type="submit" value="<">
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a more generic solution that will resize with the size of the screen you can use this example.

```css
.btnCircle {
    border-radius: 50% ;
    padding: 3vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:3vw;
    height:3vw; 
    font-size: 2vw;
    outline:none;
    border: none;
  }
  
  .btnBackgroundColor{
    background: green;
  }
  
  .btnColor{
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<button class="btnCircle btnBackgroundColor btnColor">Yes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

An round button with box-shadow https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/floating-action-buttons/

```css
.btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 4%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the actual width of an `a` tag depends on its contents. Your code has no text in the `a` tag, so it appears like a hunger-sunken circle. If you use the `div` tag along the `a`, you get the desired results.

Check this code out:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*this will rounden-up the button*/
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  /*keep the height and width equal*/
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
 <!--use the URL you want to use-->
 <button class="btn">press me</button>
 </a>
```

Comment: It's not an answer, it is the same code as in the original post, you just added a background colour.

Comment: Oh! So sorry! I change it now

Comment: @pexichdu, take a look at this now.

Comment: Now it's the same as the accepted answer. And you should **never ever** add a `button` inside an `a` tag, especially with that _Pro_ in your nickname :(

Comment: Which answer does even mention the reason for the width of the `a` tag? Ad it's just an example. A `div` can be used instead of the `button`

Answer (score 0):

you could always do

html: `<div class = "btn"> <a> <button> idk whatever you want to put in the button </button> </a> </div>`

and then do

css:
`.btn a button { border-radius: 50% }`

works perfect in my opinion