# Change the shape of action button in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Anyone know how to change the shape of a action button from a square to a circle in shiny??

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Some text:"),
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "Welcome.js")),
  tags$button(id="intro", 
              type="button", 
              class="btn action-button btn-success btn-lg ",
              strong(HTML('<i class="icon-star">  </i>Some text')))
)
```

Thanks

DC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the shape of the action button you can use CSS. One way would be:

```
.btn {
  display:block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

, source: [Circle button css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320878/circle-button-css). That would create a cirular action button.

To add CSS in your shiny app you can use `tags$head(tags$style(HTML(...)))`:

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                  .btn {
                    display:block;
                    height: 60px;
                    width: 60px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    border: 1px solid red;

                    }

                    "))
    ),
  actionButton("do", "Go!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    print(2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great and useful answer! Is there any chance you could also show how to customize the font size of the text displayed in the button? Thank you

Comment: you can try using `font-size: 22px;`. Feel free to open a new question and link it here if the hint does not work for you