# CSS click outside a circle causes event

Tags: javascript, css

I have a circle created with `border-radius`. If I click on the cut-off area, the event still fires. How do I prevent this natively? Or is the only solution to check it in JS?

Comment: what is the element the click event handler targets? a div?

Comment: You might be listening to events on something other than the element that you've clipped. Add a code example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circle button css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320878/circle-button-css)

Comment: I would add `overflow: hidden` and see if the event still fires.

Comment: bind an event handler to the `body` and within the handler check the target element

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to recreate your case and it works just fine. Both with `div`+`border-radius` approach and `svg`

```js
document.getElementById("circle1").onclick = function() {
  alert("svg clicked")
}

document.getElementById("circle2").onclick = function() {
  alert("div clicked")
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  fill="red" id="circle1"/>
</svg>

<div class="circle" id="circle2"></div>
```